# What does the word 「やで」 mean?

Tags: words, particles, kansai-ben

What does the word 「やで」 mean?

> おまえさん　とこのジョーは自{じ}分{ぶん}の身{み}を守{まも}るがためにわしらの子{こ}どもまでまきぞえにしとるん**やで**。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roughly, 「やで」 is the Kansai equivalent of the Kanto 「だよ」.  It is an affirmation sentence-ender.

「しとるんやで」≒「してるんだよ」